# How to Replace the Drivers Key Lock

Tags: pontiac

Are there any other cars that have the same type of key lock for a 1990 Pontiac Grand Prix LE? (2-door)  I'm having a hard time finding a used one.

The little door/flap on the key mechanizm is broken or has come loose and I can't lock/unlock it anymore. (I have to open the passengers side, hit the unlock switch & then get in on the drives side again.)  I would like to replace it with another lock.

(Also, how do I replace this part?)

Thanks in advance,
Matt

.

Answer (score 3):

You've got a [fifth-generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontiac_Grand_Prix#First_generation_.281962.E2.80.931968.29) [W-body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GM_W_platform) Grand Prix.  So, possibly a Buick Regal, Olds Cutlass Supreme or Chevrolet Lumina from the same year will have what you need.  Of course, your keys probably won't work with the donor cylinder(s).  A dealer can probably get you new cylinders to match your keys.  There are various online retailers, too, where you can get GM parts not too much over wholesale, certainly below retail.

An added bonus to having different cylinders and keys than what the GM information systems indicate for your VIN is that anybody with a forged bill of sale / title will get the wrong keys cut.

As to how to replace lock cylinder, you're probably going to have to take all the interior trim off the door so you can access it.  This is where a factory service manual comes in handy.  They're a bit spendy, but I prefer them to the alternatives.  You might be able to mine one of the [W-body forums](http://www.gmwbody.com/forum/) for info.  If you've got a Pick-n-Pull style of boneyard local to you, you can practice on the donor vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

remove the door panel and reach inside to release the retaining clip for the linkage then the clip that retains the lock. install the new cylinder and clip attach the linkage.The part is available at an auto parts store for under $50. As a side not this kit from Auto Parts warehouse includes two locks for the doors but your ignition will still use your old key [http://www.autopartswarehouse REPO507201

Comment: Good basic description, but I'll go on to add that it requires a great deal of patience.  There's not much room to work in there.  You have to just relax and take your time.  Rush and you'll quickly get frustrated.